# Get list of all Kafka KTables

Tags: java, ksqldb

How can I query the list of all KTables and KStreams that Kafka cluster has?

Something like `select * from all streams`

Comment: okay, I guess `show streams` would do the trick for streams

Comment: Kafka cluster doesn't have KTable or KStream, it has only topics. KTable and KStreams is abstract used in kafka streams library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tables: `show tables;`
For streams: `show streams;`